# Unit Test which verifies value is in the list

Tags: c#, moq, xunit

I have a code to do below

```
webNodeService.write("W100", new List<webNode>() { webaddress="C1", inputValue="Example" });
```

Then I want to do the unit test to verify the value of webnode

```
webNodeService.Verify(v => v.Write("W100", It.IsAny<List<webNode>>()));
```

Beside, use callback, is anyway to verify the list of webnode is my expected

Thank you

Comment: If you have a solution, stack overflow is not an appropriate venue asking for alternatives because it seems to you it's "not a simple code".

Comment: Could you please provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of It.IsAny<> you could try using:

```
It.Is<List<webNode>>(list => list.Should().Match(etc etc))
```